# How can I make VS Code colour JS function parameter references the same as their declarations?

Tags: javascript, parameters, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to pick a color for function parameters and then keep that color in the body of the function? For example:

[image: snippet 1]

I want Hello to remain ~orange on the function's body and have variables not to be white so I can differentiate between parameters and local variables.

I want to achieve this basically (webstorm):

[image: snipet 2]

Answer (score 0):

#### If token-based highlighting is being used...

See [Why don't certain VS Code themes have semantic highlighting, and how can I get semantic highlighting for them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76878302/11107541), and then read this section if you have purposely disabled semantic highlighting for all languages (see the `editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled` setting), or for JavaScript (which is the language this question post is about), or if your selected theme does not have semantic highlighting enabled by default and you have purposely not forced it to be enabled (see the `editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations` setting).

Statistically speaking, you'll probably want to skip reading this section if you're in a rush (at least for JavaScript code).

In general (I'm trying to abstract a bit away from JavaScript here- skip this paragraph if you just care about JavaScript) it's just a matter of finding out the token scopes for parameter declarations and parameter references and changing them. Use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) and figure out what token scopes you can use and update your `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` accordingly. That is... if the TextMate grammar for the language mode of interest has such token scope definitions that enable you to do that. If it doesn't, then you're out of luck.

In the case of JavaScript, if you're just using the TextMate-based syntax-highlighting that's built-in to VS Code for JavaScript (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/javascript/syntaxes/JavaScript.tmLanguage.json), then at least at the time of this writing, I think you're out of luck. When I tried using the scope inspector, I just saw this:

```
variable.other.readwrite.js
meta.block.js
meta.function.js
source.js
```

Nothing that seems like it'd allow you to change the colour of parameter references to match that of parameter declarations without messing up other non-parameter variable references.

#### If semantic highlighting is being used...

Then if your theme is colouring them differently, it's probably some idiosyncrasy (intentional or not- I have no idea) of the theme. I just went through a couple of the builtin themes and noticed that for most of them, the colour of JS parameter declarations and references are the same. In Solarized Dark, they are not. Looking at [its theme file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/theme-solarized-dark/themes/solarized-dark-color-theme.json), I'm actually not sure why. But I notice that if I manually defined a colour for [the standard `parameter` token type](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#standard-token-types-and-modifiers),

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Solarized Dark]": {
        "rules": {
            "parameter": "#ff0000"
        }
    }
}
```

then it will apply to both declarations and references. I don't understand why, but I'm not in the mood for rabbit holes right now. The deepest I'll go is to observe that in the themes where declarations and references are coloured the same, in the scope inspector, under the "semantic token type" part, I also see "`variable.parameter`", which I'm not really sure what that's about- whether it's a semantic-based or TextMate-based highlighting thing, but very notably, in [the Solarized Dark theme file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/theme-solarized-dark/themes/solarized-dark-color-theme.json), (at least at the time of this writing,) you can see the following in the `tokenColors` property:

```json
{
   "name": "Function argument",
   "scope": "variable.parameter",
   "settings": {}
},
```

, which I find quite suspicious.

Bonus tip for anyone who actually wants to do the opposite and make declarations coloured differently, then define a rule for `"parameter:declaration"` (the part after the colon is called a "[modifier](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#standard-token-types-and-modifiers)", and `declaration` is one of the standard modifiers).