# Why don't certain VS Code themes have semantic highlighting, and how can I get semantic highlighting for them?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I want to use the Tokyo Night colour theme. However, it sets variables, modules, class identifiers and properties to the same colour. I find this a bit confusing so I try to customise them to different colours. However, the Tokyo Night colour extension replaces the semantic token analyser with a TextMate-based one.

See images below. Compare VS Code's dark+ colour theme for Python, which recognises `np`'s semantic token type as a module. Tokyo Night does not recognise this.

- [darkplus_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0hNv.png)
- [tokyonight_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL5Kl.png)

How do I change the colour theme without changing the semantic analyser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might just be that the tokyo night theme hasn't enabled semantic highlighting for itself. See also https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#enablement-of-semantic-highlighting. If you look at the builtin theme JSON files of VS Code, you'll see that they have `"semanticHighlighting": true`. Ex. [in the Solarized Dark Theme](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/release/1.81/extensions/theme-solarized-dark/themes/solarized-dark-color-theme.json#L517). You can see the commit where VS Code opted in to semantic highlighting for its builtin themes here: [`41a4adb`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/41a4adb47b44fed360105ffb68d6ddf0778b25fb).

I currently don't see a line like that in in https://github.com/enkia/tokyo-night-vscode-theme/blob/master/themes/tokyo-night-color-theme.json. Actually, upon further digging (where I found [this related discussion](https://github.com/enkia/tokyo-night-vscode-theme/issues/28#issuecomment-812680005)), Tokyo Night actually *did* at one point in its past opt in to semantic highlighting. See commit [`ce2b1f1`](https://github.com/enkia/tokyo-night-vscode-theme/commit/ce2b1f101f4ea4f17c85161c822e9c68ce9ba104), but decided to opt back out in commit [`2dbedf6`](https://github.com/enkia/tokyo-night-vscode-theme/commit/2dbedf60532e6250c54e7e051552716fd77a704d).

As a theme *user* (as opposed to a theme maintainer), you can force semantic highlighting to be enabled for that theme by setting your `editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled` setting to `true`, or doing something like the following in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Tokyo Night]": {
        "enabled": true,
    },
    "[Tokyo Night Storm]": {
        "enabled": true,
    },
    "[Tokyo Night Light]": {
        "enabled": true,
    },
},
```