# No Highlighting in VS Code When Writing Python Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have little to no highlighting in my Python documents in VS Code. This happened all of a sudden and I'm not quite sure what I have done to cause this.

[image: Image of the code in question]

I have looked around at other similar questions, and I have tried changing themes. I have also tried adding `"python.languageServer": "Pylance",` to my `settings.json`, but nothing is working. My complete `settings.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "window.autoDetectColorScheme": true,
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark"
}
```

Comment: What if you remove `"python.languageServer": "Pylance",`?

Comment: just tried that, and it didn't change anything

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: the code is not the point. the color is the point

Comment: Is your python extension enabled? Does your colour theme [support semantic highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76878302/11107541)? What version of the Python extension and Pylance extension do you have installed? Does this happen if you rollback to previous versions? Please _add_ code that can be used to reproduce this problem- don't make me retype the code in your screenshot just to try to reproduce the problem. And point out instances of exactly what you don't expect to see and describe exactly what you expect to see instead.